# What are the prerequisites to understand "formal fibers"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

What are some prerequisites (within the field of Algebra) in order to understand "formal fibers"? I know that I should understand basic ring theory and polynomial rings, but what else?

Comment: Where have you encountered this? Sharing some background about your question will let people on this site help you more.

Comment: Sure. I'm considering an undergraduate research project that investigates on formal fibers (the projects says that there are many open questions in the field). I have learned group theory and a bit of ring theory, and I wonder if I might need more knowledge in algebra to prepare for it.